# Inserting rows into a child table

Tags: sqlite

I have these rows in a parent table:

```
T_PARENT (PK->PID)

PID   |   COL1      |   COL2
-----------------------------------
8     |   "C1VAL1"  |   "C2SOMEVAL"
9     |   "C1VAL1"  |   "C2SOMEVAL"
```

I have these rows in a child table:

```
T_CHILD (PK->CID, FK->T_PARENT.PID)

CID   |   PID     |   COL1   |   COL2
----------------------------------------
1     |   8       |   "VAL1" |   "VAL2"
2     |   9       |   "VAL3" |   "VAL4"
```

I can duplicate two rows of the parent using a single SQL statement only changing COL1.

```
PID   |   COL1      |   COL2
-----------------------------------
8     |   "C1VAL1"  |   "C2SOMEVAL"
9     |   "C1VAL1"  |   "C2SOMEVAL"
10    |   "C1VAL2"  |   "C2SOMEVAL"
11    |   "C1VAL2"  |   "C2SOMEVAL"
```

I don't know how to insert two corresponding rows 
in the child table using a single SQL statement to achieve this:

```
CID   |   PID     |   COL1   |   COL2
----------------------------------------
1     |   8       |   "VAL1" |   "VAL2"
2     |   9       |   "VAL3" |   "VAL4"
3     |   10      |   "VAL1" |   "VAL2"
4     |   11      |   "VAL3" |   "VAL4"
```

Basically, PID 10 needs to have the same values for 
COL1 and COL2 as PID 8, and PID 11 needs to have the 
same values for COL1 and COL2 as PID 9.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please separate code and text.

Comment: Show the statement that you're using to duplicate the parents.

Comment: INSERT INTO T_PARENT (COL1, COL2)
SELECT 'C1VAL2', COL2
FROM T_PARENT 
WHERE COL1 = 'C1VAL1';

Comment: Also, thanks to whomever separated code and text!  Will keep in mind for the future.